# Wordpress call plugin popup inside

Tags: php, wordpress

I use email-subscribers pluging. I need this plugin call popup page.I could not find how to make. If you can help I would be very happy. I hope someone can help :(
is the error I get when I call the page : **Fatal error: Class 'WP_Widget' not found in C:\wamp\www\wp-content\plugins\email-subscribers\classes\es-register.php on line 171**

My code ;

```
<?php
class es_cls_registerhook
{
    public static function es_activation()
    {
        global $wpdb;

        add_option('email-subscribers', "1.0");

        // Plugin tables
        $array_tables_to_plugin = array('es_emaillist','es_sentdetails','es_deliverreport','es_pluginconfig');
        $errors = array();

        // loading the sql file, load it and separate the queries
        $sql_file = ES_DIR.'sql'.DS.'es-createdb.sql';
        $prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
        $handle = fopen($sql_file, 'r');
        $query = fread($handle, filesize($sql_file));
        fclose($handle);
        $query=str_replace('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `','CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `'.$prefix, $query);
        $queries=explode('-- SQLQUERY ---', $query);

        // run the queries one by one
        $has_errors = false;
        foreach($queries as $qry)
        {
            $wpdb->query($qry);
        }

        // list the tables that haven't been created
        $missingtables=array();
        foreach($array_tables_to_plugin as $table_name)
        {
            if(strtoupper($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES like  '". $prefix.$table_name . "'")) != strtoupper($prefix.$table_name))  
            {
                $missingtables[]=$prefix.$table_name;
            }
        }

        // add error in to array variable
        if($missingtables) 
        {
            $errors[] = __('These tables could not be created on installation ' . implode(', ',$missingtables), ES_TDOMAIN);
            $has_errors=true;
        }

        // if error call wp_die()
        if($has_errors) 
        {
            wp_die( __( $errors[0] , ES_TDOMAIN ) );
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            es_cls_default::es_pluginconfig_default();
            es_cls_default::es_subscriber_default();
            es_cls_default::es_template_default();
            es_cls_default::es_notifications_default();
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static function es_deactivation()
    {
        // do not generate any output here
    }

    public static function es_admin_option()
    {
        // do not generate any output here
    }

    public static function es_adminmenu()
    {
        $es_c_rolesandcapabilities = get_option('es_c_rolesandcapabilities', 'norecord');
        if($es_c_rolesandcapabilities == 'norecord' || $es_c_rolesandcapabilities == "")
        {
            $es_roles_subscriber = "manage_options";
            $es_roles_mail = "manage_options";
            $es_roles_notification = "manage_options";
            $es_roles_sendmail = "manage_options";
            $es_roles_setting = "manage_options";
            $es_roles_sentmail = "manage_options";
            $es_roles_help = "manage_options";
        }
        else
        {
            $es_roles_subscriber = $es_c_rolesandcapabilities['es_roles_subscriber'];
            $es_roles_mail = $es_c_rolesandcapabilities['es_roles_mail'];
            $es_roles_notification = $es_c_rolesandcapabilities['es_roles_notification'];
            $es_roles_sendmail = $es_c_rolesandcapabilities['es_roles_sendmail'];
            $es_roles_setting = $es_c_rolesandcapabilities['es_roles_setting'];
            $es_roles_sentmail = $es_c_rolesandcapabilities['es_roles_sentmail'];
            $es_roles_help = $es_c_rolesandcapabilities['es_roles_help'];
        }

        add_menu_page( __( 'Email Subscriber', ES_TDOMAIN ), 
            __( 'Email Subscriber', ES_TDOMAIN ), 'admin_dashboard', 'email-subscribers', 'es_admin_option', ES_URL.'images/mail.png', 51 );

        add_submenu_page('email-subscribers', __( 'Subscribers', ES_TDOMAIN ), 
            __( 'Subscribers', ES_TDOMAIN ), $es_roles_subscriber, 'es-view-subscribers', array( 'es_cls_intermediate', 'es_subscribers' ));

        add_submenu_page('email-subscribers', __( 'Compose', ES_TDOMAIN ), 
            __( 'Compose', ES_TDOMAIN ), $es_roles_mail, 'es-compose', array( 'es_cls_intermediate', 'es_compose' ));

        add_submenu_page('email-subscribers', __( 'Notification', ES_TDOMAIN ), 
            __( 'Notification', ES_TDOMAIN ), $es_roles_notification, 'es-notification', array( 'es_cls_intermediate', 'es_notification' ));

        add_submenu_page('email-subscribers', __( 'Send Email', ES_TDOMAIN ), 
            __( 'Send Email', ES_TDOMAIN ), $es_roles_sendmail, 'es-sendemail', array( 'es_cls_intermediate', 'es_sendemail' ));

        add_submenu_page('email-subscribers', __( 'Settings', ES_TDOMAIN ), 
            __( 'Settings', ES_TDOMAIN ), $es_roles_setting, 'es-settings', array( 'es_cls_intermediate', 'es_settings' )); 

        add_submenu_page('email-subscribers', __( 'Roles', ES_TDOMAIN ), 
            __( 'Roles', ES_TDOMAIN ), 'administrator', 'es-roles', array( 'es_cls_intermediate', 'es_roles' ));    

        add_submenu_page('email-subscribers', __( 'Sent Mails', ES_TDOMAIN ), 
            __( 'Sent Mails', ES_TDOMAIN ), $es_roles_sentmail, 'es-sentmail', array( 'es_cls_intermediate', 'es_sentmail' ));  

        add_submenu_page('email-subscribers', __( 'Help & Info', ES_TDOMAIN ), 
            __( 'Help & Info', ES_TDOMAIN ), $es_roles_help, 'es-general-information', array( 'es_cls_intermediate', 'es_information' ));

    }

    public static function es_widget_loading()
    {
        register_widget( 'es_widget_register' );
    }   
}

function es_sync_registereduser( $user_id )
{        
    $es_c_emailsubscribers = get_option('es_c_emailsubscribers', 'norecord');
    if($es_c_emailsubscribers == 'norecord' || $es_c_emailsubscribers == "")
    {
        // No action is required
    }
    else
    {
        if(($es_c_emailsubscribers['es_registered'] == "YES") && ($user_id <> ""))
        {
            $es_registered = $es_c_emailsubscribers['es_registered'];
            $es_registered_group = $es_c_emailsubscribers['es_registered_group'];

            $user_info = get_userdata($user_id);
            $user_firstname = $user_info->user_firstname;
            if($user_firstname == "")
            {
                $user_firstname = $user_info->user_login;
            }
            $user_mail = $user_info->user_email;

            $form['es_email_name'] = $user_firstname;
            $form['es_email_mail'] = $user_mail;
            $form['es_email_group'] = $es_c_emailsubscribers['es_registered_group'];
            $form['es_email_status'] = "Confirmed";
            $action = es_cls_dbquery::es_view_subscriber_ins($form, "insert");
            if($action == "sus")
            {
                //Inserted successfully. Below 3 line of code will send WELCOME email to subscribers.
                $subscribers = array();
                $subscribers = es_cls_dbquery::es_view_subscriber_one($user_mail);
                es_cls_sendmail::es_sendmail("welcome", $template = 0, $subscribers, "welcome", 0);
            }
        }
    }   
}

class es_widget_register extends WP_Widget 
{
    function __construct() 
    {
        $widget_ops = array('classname' => 'widget_text elp-widget', 'description' => __(ES_PLUGIN_DISPLAY, ES_TDOMAIN), ES_PLUGIN_NAME);
        parent::__construct(ES_PLUGIN_NAME, __(ES_PLUGIN_DISPLAY, ES_TDOMAIN), $widget_ops);
    }

    function widget( $args, $instance ) 
    {
        extract( $args, EXTR_SKIP );

        $es_title   = apply_filters( 'widget_title', empty( $instance['es_title'] ) ? '' : $instance['es_title'], $instance, $this->id_base );
        $es_desc    = $instance['es_desc'];
        $es_name    = $instance['es_name'];
        $es_group   = $instance['es_group'];
        $es_category    = $instance['es_category'];

        echo $args['before_widget'];
        if ( ! empty( $es_title ) )
        {
            echo $args['before_title'] . $es_title . $args['after_title'];
        }
        // display widget method
        $url = home_url();

        global $es_includes;
        if (!isset($es_includes) || $es_includes !== true) 
        { 
            $es_includes = true;
            ?>
            <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="<?php echo ES_URL; ?>widget/es-widget.css" />
            <?php 
        } 
        ?>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo ES_URL; ?>widget/es-widget.js"></script>
        <div>
            <?php if( $es_desc <> "" ) { ?>

            <?php } ?>
            <div class="es_msg"><span id="es_msg"></span></div>
            <?php if( $es_name == "YES" ) { ?>
            <div class="es_lablebox"><?php _e('Name', ES_TDOMAIN); ?></div>
            <div class="es_textbox">
                <input class="es_textbox_class" name="es_txt_name" id="es_txt_name" value="" maxlength="225" type="text">
            </div>

            <div class="es_lablebox">Kategori</div>
            <div class="es_textbox">
                <select name="cb" id="cb" class="es_textbox_class">
                <option value="Demiryolu Ulaşım" selected="selected">Demiryolu Ulaşım</option>
                <option value="Denizyolu Ulaşım">Denizyolu Ulaşım</option>
                <option value="Hava Ulaşım">Hava Ulaşım</option>
                <option value="Karayolu Ulaşım">Karayolu Ulaşım</option>
                <option value="Lojistik">Lojistik</option>
                <option value="Otomotiv">Otomotiv</option>
                </select>
            </div>


            <?php } ?>
            <div class="es_lablebox"><?php _e('Email *', ES_TDOMAIN); ?></div>
            <div class="es_textbox">
                <input class="es_textbox_class" name="es_txt_email" id="es_txt_email" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13) es_submit_page('<?php echo $url; ?>')" value="" maxlength="225" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="es_button">
                <input class="es_textbox_button" name="es_txt_button" id="es_txt_button" onClick="return es_submit_page('<?php echo $url; ?>')" value="<?php _e('Subscribe', ES_TDOMAIN); ?>" type="button">
            </div>
            <?php if( $es_name != "YES" ) { ?>
                <input name="es_txt_name" id="es_txt_name" value="" type="hidden">
            <?php } ?>
            <input name="es_txt_group" id="es_txt_group" value="<?php echo $es_group; ?>" type="hidden">
        </div>
        <?php
        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }

    function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) 
    {
        $instance               = $old_instance;
        $instance['es_title']   = ( ! empty( $new_instance['es_title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['es_title'] ) : '';
        $instance['es_desc']    = ( ! empty( $new_instance['es_desc'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['es_desc'] ) : '';
        $instance['es_name']    = ( ! empty( $new_instance['es_name'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['es_name'] ) : '';
        $instance['es_group']   = ( ! empty( $new_instance['es_group'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['es_group'] ) : '';
        $instance['es_category'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['es_category'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['es_category'] ) : '';
        return $instance;
    }

    function form( $instance ) 
    {
        $defaults = array(
            'es_title' => '',
            'es_desc'   => '',
            'es_name'   => '',
            'es_group'  => '',
            'es_category' => '',
        );
        $instance       = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, $defaults);
        $es_title       = $instance['es_title'];
        $es_desc        = $instance['es_desc'];
        $es_name        = $instance['es_name'];
        $es_group       = $instance['es_group'];
        $es_category    = $instance['es_category'];
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('es_title'); ?>"><?php _e('Widget Title', ES_TDOMAIN); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('es_title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('es_title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $es_title; ?>" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('es_name'); ?>"><?php _e('Display Name Field', ES_TDOMAIN); ?></label>
            <select class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('es_name'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('es_name'); ?>">
                <option value="YES" <?php $this->es_selected($es_name == 'YES'); ?>>YES</option>
                <option value="NO" <?php $this->es_selected($es_name == 'NO'); ?>>NO</option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('es_desc'); ?>"><?php _e('Short Description', ES_TDOMAIN); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('es_desc'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('es_desc'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $es_desc; ?>" />
            <?php _e('Short description about your subscription form.', ES_TDOMAIN); ?>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('es_group'); ?>"><?php _e('Subscriber Group', ES_TDOMAIN); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('es_group'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('es_group'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $es_group; ?>" />
        </p>
        <?php
    }

    function es_selected($var) 
    {
        if ($var==1 || $var==true) 
        {
            echo 'selected="selected"';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What version of wp are you running?

Comment: I use 4.2.3–tr_TR version

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a broken WordPress installation to me. For debug, you can try to include `wp-includes/widget.php` in your file (`es-register.php`).

The Plugin works fine for me (4.2.3)!

Comment: What do you mean by "popup page"? Did you modify the original plugin? I think you should try to get the plugin working before you modify it.